# bad defsym; format is --defsym name=value

Tags: assembly, gcc, build, linker, ld

Explanation: I've created an STM32 project and aim to get a platform-independent build and output file like .hex, .bin, and .elf. For this, I created the project under the CMake build system. CMake configuration settings and toolchain settings have been made. However, towards the end of the build phase, I encountered this error.

Linker flags: Under "compiler_flags.cmake" file.

```
...

set(LD_FLAGS "-Wl,-Map=${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.map,--cref -T${LD_SCRIPT} -Wl,--gc-sections -static,--specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -Wl,--defsym,__cxa_pure_virtual=1 -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group")
```

Error output:

```
...
...
...

Assembler messages:
Fatal error: bad defsym; format is --defsym name=value
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `LDFLAGS` have mistakes:

- there should be no whitespace in `-Wl, --gc-sections`
- `-defsym ... __cxa_pure_virtual=1` should be changed to `-Wl,--defsym,__cxa_pure_virtual=1`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still the same error exists. I edited the current version of the LD_FLAGS section on the question again.

Comment: @codeluyor it's hard to comment without source code but have you regenerated build.ninja after modifying the CMakeLists.txt ?

Comment: Yes, I did the build phase again and it gives this error in step 113 out of 118 steps.

Comment: @codeluyor "I did the build phase again" - right but did you rerun cmake? Could you the actual gcc command which causes the error to the question? You can force `ninja` to print commands by running via `ninja VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: After the error, I first deleted all the folders and documents it had created under the output folder. I then ran ```cmake .. -GNinja``` again. It outputs flawlessly. Then I started the process by typing ```ninja``` or ```ninja -v```.The error occurs after running the ```ninja``` or ```ninja -v``` gcc command. Up to step 115, outputs are given without any problems and the linker works.

Comment: @codeluyor: The assembler error seems to be saying that it should be two separate arguments, `--defsym` and `name=value`.  That means you need two separate `-Wl` options to GCC, to pass two args to the linker.  Rather than one long one containing an ASCII `' '` or worse a `','`

Comment: @codeluyor: Actually, I just tested with `gcc -v` on a test program, and `-Wl` with two commas does work after all, passing `--defsym __cxa_pure_virtual=1` to `ld`.  (At least with 11.1 on my desktop.)  So the syntax in this answer does work, you don't need two `-Wl` options.  Are you sure the error message in your question matches the current command?  Your last edit totally changed how you passed that option in the other code block, without changing the error output, so it's probably not a [mcve] anymore.  I was assuming this answer had a problem until I realized that.

Comment: @codeluyor the exact gcc command would help to clarify what's going on (can be obtained by running ninja with `VERBOSE=1`).

Comment: The source of the error was in the assembler compiler toolchain definition. The problem was solved by typing ```arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe``` instead of ```arm-none-eabi-as.exe```.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the error was in the assembler compiler toolchain definition. The problem was solved by typing `arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe` instead of `arm-none-eabi-as.exe`.